# In php unit getting error Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: php, phpunit

I am learning phpunit and trying to do test on my project using phpunit. I keep on getting this  error (app\tests\UserTest::testUser Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null") whenever i test the below Usermodel function(reg_user). Also please find the testcode below as well.

```
   public function reg_user($data)
    {
        // $this->firstName = trim($data['firstname']);
        $this->set_first_name(trim($data['firstname']));
        $this->lastName = trim($data['lastname']);
        $this->email = trim($data['email']);
        $this->userName = trim($data['username']);
        $this->password = trim($data['password']);
        $hash = $this->encrypt($this->password);
        $this->roleId = trim($data['roleid']);
        $security = new Security();
        $token =  $security->emailToken();



        if ($this->check_user_exist($this->userName)) {
            $this->error[] = "username already exist";
        } elseif ($this->check_user_exist($this->userName) < 1) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO User ( firstname, lastname, email, username, passwords, roleid, token, emailverify ) VALUES ( :firstname, :lastname, :email, :username, :passwords, :roleid, :token, :emailverify )";


            $query =  $this->conn->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $result = $query->execute(array(':firstname' => $this->get_first_name(), ':lastname' => $this->lastName, ':email' => $this->email, ':username' => $this->userName, ':passwords' => $hash, ':roleid' => $this->roleId, ':token' => $token, ':emailverify' => 0));

            // send email
            $this->send_email($data['email'], $token, $data['firstname']);

           
            if ($result) {
                $this->success[] = "registerd sussecfull";
                return $result;
            }
        }
    }
```

below is my test function to test the above function

```
class UserTest extends TestCase
{
    protected $database;
    protected $conn;
    protected $handler;

    public function testUser()
    {
        $user = new User();
        $security = new Security();

        $data = [
            'firstname' => 'Jane',
            'lastname' => 'Doe',
            'email' => 'janedoe@gmail.com',
            'username' => 'wwedew',
            'password' => password_hash('password', PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 10]),
            'roleid' => 2,
            'token' => $security->emailToken(),
            'emailverify' => 0
        ];
        
        $create = $user->reg_user($data);
        $this->assertTrue($create);
    }
}
```

any advice would be usefull what i am doing wrong. I have configured the phpunit.xml file by following the documentation.

Comment: How does the connection get into the user class?

Comment: Philip, I have __contruct() function which has database connection obect instantiate(e.g $this->conn = new Database())

Comment: Ok. Nevertheless, some connection seems to be null. Without seeing the full class it's hard to tell what's going on. The stack trace should point you to the line causing the error.

Comment: @PhilipWeinke ok thanks will have a look at stack trace  again, if I still dont get it  solvedI will post the stack strace  errors and link to github of User class .

Comment: Write a test to check the Database Connection first, because this one relys on that

Comment: @WolfgangBlessen ok

Comment: Thanks guys , finally solved the issue. it was actually adding port no 8889 and mysql Socket options in my datatabase connection. now it works.